# How to avoid Fungus attack on seeds

Tags: seeds, germination, fungus

Hi am trying to germinate seeds via paper towel method   But every time my seeds got attack by fungus and seeds get damaged. Usually I take tissue paper then I place seeds on it and then I spray little water on it and then I put the tissue paper in auto seal bags/vacuum bag.  And when I open it after few days seeds all damage attacked by fungus. So how to prevent fungus attack on seeds so that I can germinate my grapes and lemon seeds.   Thanks. 
[image: image 1] 
[image: image2]
[image: mahe 3]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not surprised your seeds aren't germinating and are going mouldy. Grape seeds need cold stratification in a refrigerator for about 3 months, and won't germinate fresh, placed on kitchen paper. Inserting the whole lot on kitchen paper, damp, into a plastic bag with lemon seeds is practically guaranteed to grow  fungus and prevent the lemon seeds germinating.

Lemon seeds germinate perfectly well planted straight into a pot with potting soil in it, but you need an organically grown lemon - seeds from non organic lemons often don't germinate at all. If its a lemon you've grown yourself without use of pesticides and the like, it should be fine. The seeds must be planted fresh, so cut a lemon, extract the seeds, scrape or remove all the flesh clinging to it, and insert into potting soil in a small pot or tray. Exact instructions here http://www.1millionwomen.com.au/blog/how-grow-your-own-lemon-tree-from-seed/

Grape seeds need different treatment - extract  the seeds from your grape, soak them in clean water for 24 hours. Strain and place them into a small container with some peat moss, put a lid on the container, and place in the refrigerator for three months. After this time, you'll need to plant them into trays in starter soil (seed and cutting compost, depending where you live) and keep them under a grow light for 16 hours a day. Another method of possible germination technique, along with step by step instructions for the method I've described, are here https://www.hunker.com/13426892/how-to-grow-grapes-from-seed

Grapes are not usually grown from seed by amateur gardeners because they do not come true, so you won't know what kind of grape you might end up with once its growing, but who knows, you might find a whole new variety that's good for eating.

Comment: A very tough subject to teach and you did a super job in 4 little paragraphs.  Kudos, Bamboo.

Answer (score 3):

The fungus either came in with the paper or seed, best to make up a batch of antifungal spray and use that to begin your project- and to clean all surfaces that you have been using- fungus's are a sign of poor ventilation and unsterilized equipment in use- clean everything before you try again. hope it helps